# How to get the length of an observable in Knockout?

Tags: knockout.js, magento2

I have an observable sizeDetails in knockout and i need to get the length in knockout template. My observable is below

```
sizeDetails: ko.observable()
```

On Ajax call success i have set observable as below

```
  self.sizeDetails({sizeGuideDetails: sizeGuideDetails,
                    shopBySizeDetails: shopBySizeDetails
                  });
```

How to get sizeGuideDetails and shopBySizeDetails length  seperately in knockout template

Comment: Are `sizeGuideDetails` and `shopBySizeDetails` also objects?

Comment: @Ray. Yes. Both are objects inside SizeDetails observable

Comment: Yes. Thank you.

Comment: Would you consider accepting it? No obligation, it just makes it easier for future readers and also gives reputation points to both parties.

Comment: @Ray. I have accepted it long back. I have less reputation points  so not getting displayed.. Thank you for the answer.. !!

Comment: I think you're referring to the upvote button. To 'accept' it you have to click the check next to the answer. Welcome :)

Comment: Accepted.....:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the keys themselves are objects, we have to get their lengths like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6700/4887159).

This is more about JavaScript in general than Knockout. To get the value of a Knockout observable, you call it like a function. e.g.: `sizeDetails()`. In this case it would return the object, and then we can get individual sizes and return them in an array or whatever format suits you.

```
function getSizeDetails(){
    const sizeDetailsObject = self.sizeDetails();
    let sizes = [];
    for (var key in sizeDetailsObject) {
        //check if key exists
        if (sizeDetailsObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            //since key is sure to be an object, get its length like this:
            sizes.push(Object.keys(sizeDetailsObject[key]).length);
        }
    }
    return sizes;
};
```

You could also create a [pure Computed observable](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-pure.html), whose value updates automatically when `sizeDetails` gets updated.

```
self.sizes = ko.pureComputed(function(){
    const sizeDetailsObject = self.sizeDetails();
    let sizes = [];
    for (var key in sizeDetailsObject) {
        if (sizeDetailsObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            sizes.push(Object.keys(sizeDetailsObject[key]).length);
        }
    }
    return sizes;
}, self);
```

Now you can always get the latest sizes by calling `self.sizes()`.

---

To get their sizes individually, you can do as Erick and Bivo have mentioned in their answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
<div data-bind="html: sizeDetails().sizeGuideDetails.length"></div>
<div data-bind="html: sizeDetails().shopBySizeDetails.length"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`sizeDetails().sizeGuideDetails.length` or `sizeDetails().sizeGuideDetails().length` depending on whether `sizeGuideDetails` is an observable or not. Same with `shopBySizeDetails`.

You can use it anywhere you like it in html like:

`<span data-bind="text: sizeDetails().sizeGuideDetails().length">`

or without any html tags:

`<!-- ko if: sizeDetails().sizeGuideDetails().length > 0 -->`

some html if the condition is true

`<!-- /ko -->`

Comment: Is it right to use sizeDetails() ? SizeDetails is an observable and not an observableArray.